# How do you solve for a vector within an equation?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

I have this equation:$$ -\nu(v)\mathbf{F}(v)+\Omega(\mathbf{b\times F}(v))= -\mathbf{Q}(v) $$
I want to solve this equation to find $\mathbf{F}(v)$, but I don't really know where to start. The tip in the book is to take $\mathbf{b\times}$ the former equation and "solve the system of equations to find the components of $\mathbf{F}$ perpendicular to $\mathbf{b}$.

Does anyone have any insights?

Further to some comments, I have tried the tip, and got stuck here

$$-\nu \mathbf{b \times F}+\Omega\mathbf{b \times (b \times F)} = -\mathbf{b \times Q} \\ \nu(\mathbf{b \times F}) + \Omega[\mathbf{(b \cdot F)b - (b \cdot b)F}]=-\mathbf{b\times Q}$$

But I don't know where to go from here, to find the next steps.

Comment: What is $\Omega$? A constant?

Comment: Yes, $\Omega$=constant

Comment: did you try to use the tip, yet?

Comment: @mgmf46 Is $Q$ related to $b$ or $F$ in any way? And $\nu$ is a scalar function I assume?

Comment: @hal4math, there are no further relations between Q/b/F than this equation. And $\nu$ is a scalar function

Comment: Anyway, I think, write out the tip and look what happens component-wise.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider operation of $\mathbf b\times \mathbf F$ as a multiplication by dual matrix:

$$
\mathbf b\times\mathbf F = \begin{pmatrix}0&-b_3&b_2\\b_3&0&-b_1\\-b_2&b_1&0\end{pmatrix}\mathbf F= \mathbf B\mathbf F
$$

At the same time you can consider $-\nu\mathbf F=-\nu\mathbf I\mathbf F$, where $\mathbf I$ is identity matrix.

Thus, your equation can be rewritten as:
$$
(\Omega\mathbf B - \nu\mathbf I)\mathbf F = \mathbf Q,\\
\mathbf F=(\Omega\mathbf B - \nu\mathbf I)^{-1}\mathbf Q
$$